# validate Regular Expression using Java

Tags: java, regex

I need validate a String using a Regular Expression, the String must be like "createRobot(x,y)", where x and y are digits.

I have Something like

```
    String ins; 

    Pattern ptncreate= Pattern.compile("^createRobot(+\\d,\\d)");
    Matcher m = ptncreate.matcher(ins);
    System.out.println(m.find());
```

but doesn't work

Can you help me ?.

Thanks.

Comment: If it should be createRobot, why do you have only "create" in the expression?

Comment: I forgot to post it, but in the code I have "createRobot", sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the word `Robot` in your pattern. Also, parenthesis are special characters in regex, and the `+` should be placed after the `\d`, not after a `(`:

```
Pattern.compile("^createRobot\\(\\d+,\\d+\\)$")
```

Note that if you want to validate input that should consist solely of this `"createRobot"`-string, you mind as well do:

```
boolean success = s.matches("createRobot\\(\\d+,\\d+\\)");
```

where `s` is the `String` you want to validate. But if you want to retrieve the numbers that were matched, you *do* need to use a Pattern/Matcher:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("createRobot\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("createRobot(12,345)");
if(m.matches()) {
  System.out.printf("x=%s, y=%s", m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

As you can see, after calling `Matcher.matches()` (or `Matcher.find()`), you can retrieve the **n<sup>th</sup>** match-group through `group(n)`.

Comment: Thanks very much, really works, there is any way to obtain digits "x" and "y" ?

Comment: that's exactly what i'm searching for, Thank you !! a final question , can you give me a web page or another resource where I can learn more about Regular Expressions ?

Comment: @JuanS, the best online resource is: http://www.regular-expressions.info . And if you have some coins to spare, [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/) is well worth it!

Answer (score 0):

You must add `\` before `(` because `(` in regex is the special group character

The regexp pattren is:
    ^create(\d+,\d+)